карусель выходит за рамки блока
карусель выходит за рамки блока и не знаю как исправить. Просьба строго не судить, я - новичок. Мне кажется что я уже все перечитала и все перепробовала, но вдруг тут подскажут. строгой ширины блоку не задавала если что.
html код
</div class ="container"
<div class="wrapper"
<div class="repair"
</div>

<div class="slider">
                   <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide">
                       <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                           <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                           <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                           <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                       </ol>
                       <div class="carousel-inner">
                           <div class="carousel-item active">
                               <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/img repair.png" alt="First slide">
                           </div>
                           <div class="carousel-item">
                               <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/img repair.png" alt="Second slide">
                           </div>
                           <div class="carousel-item">
                               <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/img repair.png" alt="Third slide">
                           </div>
                       </div>
                       <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button"
                           data-slide="prev">
                           <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                           <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                       </a>
                       <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button"
                           data-slide="next">
                           <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                           <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                       </a>
                   </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>

scss код
.promo {
    .feedback {

        &__main {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;

        }
    }


    .wrapper {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: stretch;
        padding: 60px 0 0 0;
        margin-bottom: 30px;

        .slider {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;
            position: relative;

            .update-img img,
            .calendar img {
                height: 350px;
            }

            .service-map {

                .map {
                    z-index: 0;
                    position: relative;
                }

                .mapinfo {
                    position: absolute;
                    z-index: 1;
                    margin-top: 3px;
                    margin-left: 5px;
                    border-radius: 3px;
                    box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
                    background-color: #fff;
                    width: 230px;
                    height: 122px;
                    padding: 10px;
                    text-align: center;

                    .name {
                        font-weight: 700;
                        font-size: 12px;
                    }

                    address {
                        margin-top: 10px;
                        font-size: 9px;
                    }

                    a {
                        font-size: 12px
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        .repair {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            text-align: center;

            &__data {
                margin-bottom: 50px;

                .title {
                    line-height: 173%;
                    letter-spacing: 1.2px;
                    margin-top: 0;
                }

                .address {
                    font-size: 15px;
                    font-weight: 400;

                    &:before {
                        content: url('../icons/map-pointer.svg');
                        margin-right: 2px;
                    }
                }

                .phone {
                    a {

                        display: block;
                        text-decoration: none;
                        margin-top: 20px;
                        font-size: 20px;
                        font-weight: 400;
                        text-decoration: underline;
                    }
                }
            }

            &__info {
                margin-bottom: 50px;

                .title {
                    line-height: 173%;
                    letter-spacing: 1.2px;
                }

                .descr {
                    font-size: 16px;
                    width: 800px;
                    line-height: 162.7%;
                    letter-spacing: 1px
                }
            }


            .offer {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                margin-bottom: 50px;

                .title {
                    margin-bottom: 30px;
                }

                .form {
                    flex-direction: column;

                    .form-group {
                        margin-bottom: 23px;

                        input {
                            margin: 0 auto;
                            font-size: 13px;

                        }

                        label {
                            margin-bottom: 18px;
                            font-size: 15px;
                            text-align: center;
                        }
                    }



                }
            }

        }
    }

}

scss код для класса carousel
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%; // Позволяет карусели занимать всю доступную ширину родительского элемента
    max-width: 100%; // Убирает фиксированную максимальную ширину, чтобы не было переполнения
    height: 360px; // Фиксированная высота карусели
    position: relative;

    .carousel-inner {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%; 

        .carousel-item {
            img {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                object-fit: cover;
            }
        }
    }

    .carousel-control-prev,
    .carousel-control-next {
        width: 51px;
        height: 51px;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: $main-color;
    }

    .carousel-control-prev {
        left: -50px; 
    }

    .carousel-control-next {
        right: -50px; 
    }

    .carousel-control-prev-icon,
    .carousel-control-next-icon {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}

и вот что получается на выходе и то, что я хочу исправить

